# SearchContext - Search Multiple DataObjects With 1 Form?

Tags: silverstripe

I have 3 dataobjects that have the same 4 fields I want to search.

Is it possible to have 1 form to search all of them at once, or do I have to use 3 different search forms?

Using the basic code from the docs below on my pagetype I want to search from:

```
public function DataObjectSearch() {
    $context = singleton('DataObject1')->getCustomSearchContext();
    $fields = $context->getSearchFields();
    $form = new Form($this, "DataObjectSearch",
        $fields,
        new FieldList(
            new FormAction('doSearch')
        )
    );
    return $form;
}


public function doSearch($data, $form) {
    $context = singleton('Dataobject1')->getCustomSearchContext();
    $results = $context->getResults($data);
    return $this->customise(array(
        'Results' => $results
    ))->renderWith('DataObject1Template');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never really use this, but I guess if your DataObjects have the same fields you could call the `getResults()` function multiple times and merge it all together.

```
public function doSearch($data, $form)
{
    $context = singleton('Dataobject1')->getCustomSearchContext();
    $results = ArrayList::create( $context->getResults($data)->toArray() );

    $context = singleton('Dataobject2')->getCustomSearchContext();
    $results->merge( $context->getResults($data)->toArray() );

    $context = singleton('Dataobject3')->getCustomSearchContext();
    $results->merge( $context->getResults($data)->toArray() );

    //...and so on....

    return $this->customise(array(
        'Results' => $results
    ))->renderWith('DataObject1Template');
}
```

`getResults()` apparently returns a `DataList`, so it is converted to an `ArrayList` to be able to merge results together. Haven't tested all this but hopefully it can give you pointers or ideas.

Comment: I'm just getting around to this now. Thanks for the reply.

How do I edit the DataObjectSearch() function to include the multiple DataObjects? I tried myself, but not sure if I did it wrong or it just doesn't work.

I get the error Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: $fields must be a valid FieldList instance

Comment: the error probably comes from `getCustomSearchContext` which should be defined on your `DataObject`s. Might be useful to see the code of one of your `DataObject` to see how it looks.

Comment: I don't think that is my problem. I can get 1 DO search working fine. The problem is when I do multiple ones.

In my code above, you gave me the updated doSearch() code, but I guessed on what I had to change in my DataObjectSearch() function.

This is what I put. http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/52291362822b8

Comment: Why did you change `DataObjectSearch`, this was returning your search form, not doing the actual search, like in the answer above `doSearch($data, $form)` does. Also, best thing is for you to post your whole controller and dataObjects code, will be easier to debug.

Comment: Ya that makes sense. Using the original code works, so that's great.

I do have a few questions to refine the results, but first I'm noticing that my renderWith() template is the only template being returned. It is stored in my Layout folder - DOSearchResults.ss. Page.ss is not being rendered with DoSearchResults.ss in it. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: have you tried using an array like `->renderWith(array('DOSearchResults', 'Page'))`?

Comment: Weird. I had tried that a few weeks ago when I first started this and it didn't work. Now it seems to. Last question, and not sure this is possible but is there a way to loop through the $Results and group them by DataObject? While my DOs have 4 fields in common with same name used for searching, they have multiple different fields and amounts, so I need a nice way to display them as the variable names are going to be different and the table I use won't have the same amount of columns for each. I need to display them by DataObject with their own $vars.

Comment: 2 solutions for grouping: 1) with the code above, in your template use `<% loop $Results %>` with `<% if $ClassName == 'Dataobject2' %>` to only use certain classes from the result set. OR solution 2) update the above code, saving each result set in a different variable `$resultSet1 = ArrayList::create( $context->getResults($data)->toArray() );` and update the customise method `->customise(array('Result1' => $resultSet1, 'Result2' => $resultSet2))` then use `<% loop $Result1 %>`, `<% loop $Result2 %>` and so on in your template...

Comment: I've been using your solution which works perfectly. However, upgrading to 3.1 there is a slight issue. I have 2 select fields for picking Enum values on the search form. With 3.0 the default value in the select drop down was "any" and allowed the user to leave that option blank. With 3.1 that is gone, and the select field is defaulted to the first value. So a user has to search with a value selected for the select fields, even if they don't want any. Have you run across this? Should I post a new topic on this issue?

Comment: I think it must be related to the `DropdownField` itself, API might have changed. But you can easily add a blank entry to the field with `$field->setEmptyString('Empty label')` or `$field->setHasEmptyDefault(true)`. Best if you post in a new question. Easier to answer than in a comment.